# Getting InvalidCastException depending on the number of rows

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, casting

I've been getting an InvalidCastException on the return line of this method

```
        public List<ItemClass> getAll()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Query");
        var list = (from i in db.Items
                    select i.getItem());
        Console.WriteLine("Done Query");
        return list.ToList<ItemClass>();
    }
```

I'm thinking it has something to do with the ToList method.

Funny part is that I have 4 records in the table. The query returns all of them (I know it says .getItem(). The getItem returns an object of type Item. Now i get InvalidCastException 4 times when I press continue in visual studio. On the 5th time I click continue, I get the output expected.

Here is  the exception text + output.

```
 A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.dll
    System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>AppointmentBookingSystem.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.InvalidCastException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Specified cast is not valid.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)
       at Read_ItemClass(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at AppointmentBookingSystem.ServiceItems.getAll() in c:\Users\Kim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AppointmentBookingSystem\AppointmentBookingSystem\ServiceItems.cs:line 20
       at AppointmentBookingSystem.DatabaseExplorer.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Kim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AppointmentBookingSystem\AppointmentBookingSystem\DatabaseExplorer.cs:line 27
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&amp;amp; m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&amp;amp; msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at AppointmentBookingSystem.Program.Main() in c:\Users\Kim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AppointmentBookingSystem\AppointmentBookingSystem\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)
       at Read_ItemClass(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at AppointmentBookingSystem.ServiceItems.getAll() in c:\Users\Kim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AppointmentBookingSystem\AppointmentBookingSystem\ServiceItems.cs:line 20
       at AppointmentBookingSystem.DatabaseExplorer.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Kim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AppointmentBookingSystem\AppointmentBookingSystem\DatabaseExplorer.cs:line 27
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&amp;amp; m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&amp;amp; msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at AppointmentBookingSystem.Program.Main() in c:\Users\Kim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AppointmentBookingSystem\AppointmentBookingSystem\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
    A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.dll
    System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>AppointmentBookingSystem.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.InvalidCastException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Specified cast is not valid.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)
       at Read_ItemClass(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at AppointmentBookingSystem.ServiceItems.getAll() in c:\Users\Kim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AppointmentBookingSystem\AppointmentBookingSystem\ServiceItems.cs:line 20
       at AppointmentBookingSystem.DatabaseExplorer.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Kim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AppointmentBookingSystem\AppointmentBookingSystem\DatabaseExplorer.cs:line 27
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&amp;amp; m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&amp;amp; msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at AppointmentBookingSystem.Program.Main() in c:\Users\Kim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AppointmentBookingSystem\AppointmentBookingSystem\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)
       at Read_ItemClass(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at AppointmentBookingSystem.ServiceItems.getAll() in c:\Users\Kim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AppointmentBookingSystem\AppointmentBookingSystem\ServiceItems.cs:line 20
       at AppointmentBookingSystem.DatabaseExplorer.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Kim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AppointmentBookingSystem\AppointmentBookingSystem\DatabaseExplorer.cs:line 27
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&amp;amp; m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&amp;amp; msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at AppointmentBookingSystem.Program.Main() in c:\Users\Kim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AppointmentBookingSystem\AppointmentBookingSystem\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
    A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.dll
    System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>AppointmentBookingSystem.vshost.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.InvalidCastException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>Specified cast is not valid.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)
       at Read_ItemClass(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at AppointmentBookingSystem.ServiceItems.getAll() in c:\Users\Kim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AppointmentBookingSystem\AppointmentBookingSystem\ServiceItems.cs:line 20
       at AppointmentBookingSystem.DatabaseExplorer.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Kim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AppointmentBookingSystem\AppointmentBookingSystem\DatabaseExplorer.cs:line 27
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&amp;amp; m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&amp;amp; msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at AppointmentBookingSystem.Program.Main() in c:\Users\Kim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AppointmentBookingSystem\AppointmentBookingSystem\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)
       at Read_ItemClass(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at AppointmentBookingSystem.ServiceItems.getAll() in c:\Users\Kim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AppointmentBookingSystem\AppointmentBookingSystem\ServiceItems.cs:line 20
       at AppointmentBookingSystem.DatabaseExplorer.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Kim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AppointmentBookingSystem\AppointmentBookingSystem\DatabaseExplorer.cs:line 27
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&amp;amp; m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&amp;amp; msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at AppointmentBookingSystem.Program.Main() in c:\Users\Kim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AppointmentBookingSystem\AppointmentBookingSystem\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
    Name 1 12
    Name2 2 12
    Name3 3 12
    Name4 4 12
```

ItemClass:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AppointmentBookingSystem
{
    public class ItemClass
    {
        private int itemId;

        public int ItemId
        {
            get { return itemId; }
            set { itemId = value; }
        }
        private string itemName;

        public string ItemName
        {
            get { return itemName; }
            set { itemName = value; }
        }
        private double itemPrice;

        public double ItemPrice
        {
            get { return itemPrice; }
            set { itemPrice = value; }
        }

        public ItemClass(int idIn, string nameIn, double priceIn) 
        {
            itemId = idIn;
            itemName = nameIn;
            itemPrice = priceIn;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: pls show your `ItemClass` class

Comment: If you return from your function IEnumerable<Object> 
and change statement "return list.ToList<ItemClass>()" 
in to "return list.ToList()" 
does the error disappeared?

Comment: @MaxKvt Nope, still same errors. Could it be that it has something to do with the table's datatypes? Seems like it throws exception at the .GetInt32() part.

Comment: @KimScicluna pls check datatypes of your class properties and database columna..think there is a mismatch there.

Comment: @Amitd I have a string name, int itemId,and a System.Nullable<int> Price.

Comment: Why are you select i.getItem(), if you have alreay db.Items ? 
You can interate over db.Items and convert/map each item from db in to ItemClass

Comment: @MaxKvt That's what I was doing before I implemented the ItemClass. I thought having an ItemClass would fix this. I also find it very strange that it throws the exception as many time as there is rows in the table then displays a good output.

Comment: Can you try changing the "Enable Just My Code" in Tools -> Options -> Debugging.

Comment: @Amila It was enabled. I disabled it. Is there anything I could try to further debug the problem?

Comment: Your "Name" field is on the first place, and Id on the second. Where the code that fetch data from the db? Try to play with the positions.

Comment: No sure sorry, I once got an issue like that which was fine after enabling just my code, and I think the issue you are having might just be the debugger braking on things that it should not normally do. If you run your app outside VS does it work fine ?

Comment: @MaxKvt All constructors and tables have the same order: ID, Name and Price.

Comment: @Amila Nope it still throws the inalidcastexception when i run the executable. Was worth a try.

Comment: try to swap "Name" and "Id" the the constructor

Comment: @MaxKvt No luck with that either.

Comment: judging by the stack trace the problem is in the data acquisition, not the casting. Please show us what db.Items is and how it's loaded from DB

Comment: @slawekwin I'm getting data from the database by using a DataContext db and passing the connection string as a parameter to my local database. Then I am using db.[table name] to access any tables.

Comment: I understand that ItemClass is the data model definition in this case? I assume that ItemId is defined as int and not null in the table?

Comment: @slawekwin It is not a null. As you can see at the end of the output, after the invalid cast exceptions the output comes out as expected.

Comment: a suggestion use 'mapper' casting entity as list

Comment: Made a database with SQL Server instead of a local database. Fixed, for some reason.